# Why do I have super vision in purely red light?

Tags: human-physiology

I installed some RGBW led strips in my apartment recently.. by some I mean everything is now lit by led strips and there isn't a single light bulb left.

One thing I've noticed over the last few days is that my eyesight is significantly sharper in pure red light. Historically I've had pretty good sight but reaching 30's I've developed some nearsightedness. I don't wear glasses since I can still see things up to ~2m from me as clear as ever but reading street signs now requires me to get closer and stuff like that.

Things that require me to squint and really try hard in daylight (or white light emitted by the led's) are really easy to look at in red light. My vision is worse in blue light and worst in green light. Is there any kind of common explanation for this?